# Any two perfect totally disconnected compact metric space are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Prove that any two perfect, totally disconnected , compact metric spaces are homeomorphic.

This was asked in my analyis quiz and althogh I tried to solve it at home also but I am unable to.
I took (X,d) and (Y,d') as metric spaces but I am not able to find homeomorphic map.

So, can you please help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Those are properties of the Cantor set, so in essence you are proving that any metric space with those properties is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. For the proof, for instance, see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.1008.pdf . Apparently this is (in a slightly different form) a theorem of Brouwer. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space#Characterization .

Out of curiosity, what sort of analysis quiz has this as a question, and what background knowledge are you supposed to have in order to answer it? Did your course cover the Cantor set and its characterisation above?

Comment: We are having a analysis course ( 3nd course in analysis to be precise). Topics covered  are similar to 1st course in topology.